# How to pass a parameter as an input to powershell script when it prompts?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am new to powershell. "dt setup" is the command which I am trying to automate and the file name is dtSetupAutomation.ps1. This command will prompt me for UserMailId and UserName followed by which I have to press enter. I coded to get the UserMailId and UserName as mandatory parameters but i dont know how to provide it as input when the command prompts.
Can anyone please help me?
dtSetupAutomation.ps1:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$UserMailId,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [Security.SecureString]$UserFullName
)
dt setup
```

## what "dt setup" prompts:

The script will stop for every prompts in each line that starts with a question mark, as given below:

```
PS C:\> dt setup
 ====> Git Proxy configuration
? Allow devtool to manage your github proxy settings in the .gitconfig file? [? for help] (Y/n) Y
? Your email: [? for help] preethibe.91@gmail.com
? Your full name: [? for help] Preethi Palanisamy
 ====> Github token creation
? You already have a valid token. Skip token creation? (Y/n) Y
====== Git configuration ======
Git user.name: Preethi Palanisamy
Git user.email: preethibe.91@gmail.com
...
PS C:\>
```

Comment: What is `dt`? It's not a native Windows utility or a cmd/PowerShell keyword or command... In any case, please post the code you want help with (eg. the contents of `dtSetupAutomation.ps1`)

Comment: "dt setup" is used to configure github environment @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Alright. The answer depends on whether you're prompted to pass an argument to a mandatory parameter declared in the script, or whether its because you didn't pass some mandatory argument to `dt` when you invoke it. As I mentioned above, you'll need to show us the code in any case :)

Comment: updated @MathiasR.Jessen could you please help..?

Comment: This is more related to `dt` than PowerShell. I'm not familiar with it; recommend checking out the documentation with `dt /?` or `dt -h` or `dt --help` to see what's available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved my issue:

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
.\dt.exe setup $myshell.sendkeys("Y") $myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}") $myshell.sendkeys("preethix.palanisamy@intel.com") $myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}") $myshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```